# How to retrieve the page number we are currently on, while using an antd table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have created a table with the Antd in Reactjs. I have used 50 rows per page and I have around 6 pages that come up in the pagination.
I have added an index column to the table, which loops from 1 to 50 on every page. 
Rather I need it to loop from 1 to full length. So when I navigate to page 2, It must show 51 to 100, whereas in my case it loops from 1 to 50 again. I made use of "index",that is passed from the "render" function in the table.

```
function indexRenderer(text, record, index) {
    return index+1
}
```

Is there any seperate function I can use to retrieve the page count alone from the pagination of antd.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `onChange` function of Pagination component.

It will be called with `page` parameter.

Check this out for more information:

https://ant.design/components/pagination/